# How does Indexed work in terms of sparse array

Tags: tensors, sparse-arrays, index

I want to use indexed given that s is an element [0,500] but I am unsure how to write that without getting a format error or a tensor error.

```
Δt = .0001;
t = .0833;
σ = .2183;
Δs = 5;
s = [0, 500];
μ = ((σ^2 Indexed[s, i]^2)/
    Indexed[Δs, i]^2*Δt);
α = (Indexed[s, i]/(
   2*Indexed[Δs, i]^2*Δt));
cn1[k2_, n_] = 
 SparseArray[{{m_, m_} -> 
    1/2 + 1/2*μ + 
     1/2*Indexed[rate, {k2, n}]*Δt, {m_, l_} /; 
     l - m == 1 -> -(1/4)*μ - 
     1/2*Indexed[rate, {k2, n}]*α, {m_, l_} /; 
     m - l == 1 -> -(1/4)*μ + 
     1/2*Indexed[rate, {k2, n}]*α}, {101, 101}]
```

Comment: One of the many points is that you write `Indexed[\[CapitalDelta]s, i]` while `\[CapitalDelta]s` equals `5`. That just does not make sense because you can index only into lists or arrays. Also `s = [0, 500];` is meaningless in _Mathematica_. Maybe you mean `s = {0, 500};`. Also, I am quite sure that you should use `cn1[k2_, n_] := ...` (`SetDelayed`) instead of `cn1[k2_, n_] = ...` (`Set`).

Comment: I have corrected your points, thank you! My first question is, after making those changes and commenting out the Delta S, there is no out.  Although, in terms of the ````\[CapitalDelta]=5````, the reason I did this is because when I derived my equations, I found some ````s_i```` and some ````\[CapitalDelta]s```` and I assumed for every S I needed to do it in terms of time hence why I added the delta in the question. You are saying it does not make sense because it is only single value which defeats the purpose of indexed? @HenrikSchumacher

Comment: "You are saying it does not make sense because it is only single value which defeats the purpose of indexed? " Yes.

Answer (score 1):

I find the pattern-based way of using `SparseArray` not overly helpful in practice, but that's probably a matter of taste. However, you might find this way to construct the matrix easier.  I am using just any constants for  `Δt`, `μ`, and `α`.

This is what you run once:

```
Δt = .0001;
μ = 1.;
α = 1.;

A = Plus[
   DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[ConstantArray[1/2 + μ/2, 101]]],
   DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[ConstantArray[ -μ/4, 100]], 1],
   DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[ConstantArray[ -μ/4, 100]], -1]
   ];

B = Plus[
   DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[ConstantArray[ Δt/2, 101]]],
   DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[ConstantArray[-α/2, 100]], 1],
   DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[ConstantArray[ α/2, 100]], -1]
   ];
```

And in each time step of Crank-Nicolson (I guess you are about to implement Crank-Nicolson, right), you obtain the matrix you seek for with

```
L = A + Indexed[rate, {k2, n}] B
```

Comment: Ah yes I was having an issue combining my two sparse arrays! Thank you so much for this clarification! Although I did have one question, why is it that indexed stays in the sparse array you get as an output for L? I assumed that, yes, the output would be sectioned off into four parts: namely ````(1,2),(1,1),(2,1), and (2,3)```` but it does not combine lets say the ````1/2+_```` and rather just prints it out next to the indexed function @Henrik Schumacher

Comment: Also, since the code has changed wouldn't the ````k2```` change as well? since it is no longer defined @HenrikSchumacher

Comment: Well, it is hard for me to help you here because I do not know why you introduced the parameters `k2` and `n` in the first place. That's really something that you have to make your mind up about for yourself.

Comment: "I assumed that, yes, the output would be sectioned off into four parts: namely (1,2),(1,1),(2,1), and (2,3)  [...]" Sorry, I absolutely do not understand what you mean. "[...]  rather just prints it out next to the indexed function [...]" Same problem here. But maybe your issue is simply that `rate` is still undefined and not a matrix?

Comment: I introduced ````k2```` and ````n```` because those were supposed to be independent variables that represent sequence number and time state, respectively. Also, I meant to say that for example one section of an output I got was ````(1,2)->-(1.19x10^-6Indexed[{0,5000},{i}]^2)/(Indexed[5,i]^2)````. Because the word  ````indexed```` is printing out in my code, does that mean there is an issue with the iterative method of ````S_i```` . Also if I had questions on how to add my ````\[CapitalDelta]s```` should I make a new thread for that? @HenrikSchumacher

Comment: "Because the word `Indexed` is printing out in my code, does that mean there is an issue with the iterative method of $S_i$." Quite likely yes. You should basically use `Indexed` like `Part`.

Comment: I will revise and create a new thread ! @Henrik Schumacher

Comment: To clarify, you said: "And in each time step of Crank-Nicolson (I guess you are about to implement Crank-Nicolson, right), you obtain the matrix you seek for with" ````L = A + Indexed[rate, {k2, n}] B
```` Why did you use ````indexed```` here and not just multiply A by the inverse of B  @HenrikSchumacher

Comment: Because I assumed that `L` (and not `B`) is the matrix you have to invert. But do you get it? I have to _assume_ quite a lot here because you do not give detailed information. Actually, this is absolutely independent of the CN-scheme; I just tried to build the matrix _that you had asked for_. Really, this discussion is getting us nowhere and I won't continue it; I'm off now.